# Mysql Date in where clasue?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here is my stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `simplesign`.`GetTenantTaskBetweenDate` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTenantTaskBetweenDate`(
   IN tid VARCHAR(100), 
   IN fromdate DATE ,
   IN todate DATE, 
   IN searchvalue VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT RequestID 
     FROM task 
    WHERE ( (TenantID=tid) 
      AND Create_date BETWEEN fromdate AND todate) 
      AND (File_name LIKE searchvalue || File_title LIKE searchvalue) 
    ORDER BY Create_date DESC;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

I want all `ReuestID` from `task` table in following cases:

- If fromdate and todate is null then search by searchValue
- if fromdate, todate and searchValue is not null then search by all three inputs
- if from fromdate or todate is null then serach by searchValue
- if searchValue is null then search by fromdate and todate
- If all three input is null then search normally like `(select * from)`

Please help me out to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you wan't to use all conditions passed if they are not null

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `simplesign`.`GetTenantTaskBetweenDate` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetTenantTaskBetweenDate`(
   IN tid VARCHAR(100), 
   IN fromdate DATE ,
   IN todate DATE, 
   IN searchvalue VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
   SELECT RequestID 
     FROM task 
    WHERE (tid is null OR TenantID=tid)
      AND (fromdate is null OR Create_date >= fromdate) 
      AND (todate is null OR Create_date <= todate)
      AND (searchvalue is null OR File_name LIKE searchvalue OR File_title LIKE searchvalue) 
    ORDER BY Create_date DESC;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thank you for quick response,its working for dates only if i pass blank search value then it returns 0 records.:(

Comment: 1+ for quick response...:)

Comment: If you need to send anything else than null as input then you need to change the conditions to also ignore empty strings in the same way as null.